# Is there a way to associate an action on a trace event in dbx

Tags: debugging, dbx

Here is what I'm trying to acheive :

For every malloc call in my application, I want to dump out the stack trace (to find out who is making malloc calls) and I need to track this over a period of time.

I know that we can use trace command in dbx, but it just dumps out one parent level, which is not really useful for me. So, I want to know if we can kind of associated `where` command on every trace event.

My applications are built for Solaris and I'm using dbx V8.0.

Comment: Maybe `when in malloc { where; }`

Comment: There is also built-in support for memory leak checking. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-1380/blahq.html